# Incremental count based on criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there anyway that I can archive like the following?
Basically it need to count based on the subject itself.

```
Student     Term        Subject     Count
------------------------------------------------------
0001        AUG2013     ABC1234     0
0001        Jan2014     ABC1234     1
0001        Jan2014     DEF1234     0
0001        May2014     ABC1234     2
0001        May2014     GHI1234     0
```

Comment: See how to perform Running Total on tsql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT
   Student,
   Term,
   Subject,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student, Subject ORDER BY Term)-1 AS Count
FROM 
   TableName
```

Comment: ive made an edit to subtract 1 since ROW_NUMBER() starts at 1.